# How to set a placeholder for an autocomplete hiddenfor field in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have no clue how to make my place holder get applied for the hiddenfor field

Please check the code i used in my views :

[image: code i used in my views]

And here is the output :

[image]

Comment: I have used @Value=Model.Operationunit==String.Empty?" ":Model.Operationunit.tostring(); line also in the code but i got no changes in the output .

Comment: why do you want a placeholder in a hidden input?

Comment: Try to use `TextBoxFor()` extension method instead of `HiddenFor()` because as the name suggests `HiddenFor()` creates a hidden element in the form for the model property that you passed. While `TextBoxFor()` creates an input element for the specified property with proper type. On this element placeholder will be displayed as you wish.